# Get SQL records matching multiple lines conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

I have such a table (simplified for exhibit) with SQLServer 2012:

| ParentId | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 1 |
| 11111 | 2 |
| 22222 | 1 |
| 22222 | 2 |
| 22222 | 3 |
| 33333 | 1 |

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/67a210/1

I'm using a SP with a parameter `@filterIds`, which contains a string like `1, 2, 3` (note the delimiter is comma **and** space).

I need a request to get all the lines with a same `ParentId` which has a `Val` of all values of `@filtersIds`.

If `@filtersId` is `1, 2, 3`, result must be 22222 because it's the only one which has lines with Val = 1, Val = 2 and Val = 3.
If `@filtersId` is `1, 2`, results must be 11111 and 22222 because they both have lines with Val  = 1 and Val = 2.
If `@filtersId` is `1, 4`, there's no result at all because there's no ParentId with Val = 1 and Val = 4.

I tried with some JOIN but it seems over-complicated for a such a simple request. Is there some quick-and-easy solution I haven't think about ?

Comment: Are a `ParentId` and `Val` pair unique?

Comment: You can Pass table-valued parameters to the stored procedure for that. Did you check tvp for your problem?

Comment: This is Relational Division With Remainder

Answer (score 0):

You can build a filter table and find all the parentID values that don't have a filter criteria that isn't met.

Note that you can bypass the first step (where I build the filter list cteFilter from values in the data) using the function STRING_SPLIT if your SQL is new enough, but I showed the version you'll need for older SQL.

Also note that using integer values matched against a string filter presents an unusual problem - you can have a value match a *part* of the intended filter value, i.e. if your filter is '100, 250' you need to take steps to insure a value of 25 does not match. Adding delimiters around both the filter string and the strings generated from the values will allow you to test for only a complete match.

Thanks for providing sample data in Fiddle, it made it easier to answer your question.

```
DECLARE @Filter nvarchar(50) = '1, 2, 3'; 
--DECLARE @Filter nvarchar(50) = '1, 2'; 
create table #Sample(parentId int not null, Val int not null)

insert into #Sample(parentId, Val)
values (11111, 1), (11111, 2), (22222, 1), (22222, 2), (22222, 3), (33333, 1)

;with cteVals as ( --Don't apply functions more than necessary
    SELECT DISTINCT Val FROM #Sample 
), cteFilter as (--NOTE: For QL Server 2016 (13.x) and later, use string_split to generate this list!
    SELECT Val --Otherwise, build a list by finding all Val values in your filter string
    FROM cteVals --Next line is complicated to insure matching start and end values
        --even if values are of different lengths, we don't want 25 to match filter '100, 250'!
    WHERE CHARINDEX(CONCAT(', ', FORMAT(Val, '#'),', '), CONCAT(', ', @Filter, ', ')) > 0
)SELECT DISTINCT parentId --Find all of the ParentIDs
FROM #Sample as S 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( --That don't have any filter requirements ...
    SELECT * FROM cteFilter as F 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( --such that the filter
        SELECT * FROM #Sample as S2 --isn't in the sample data
        WHERE S2.Val = F.Val   --matching the filter value
            AND S2.parentId = S.parentId  --and also matching the parentID in question
        )
    )
DROP TABLE #Sample
```

EDIT: Credit to Joe Celko, I used his article https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/ in troubleshooting my solution, which originally did not work

Answer (score 0):

**This is a case of *Relational Division With Remainder*.** There are a number of solutions.

An implementation that is usually more efficient than the other answer gave (a doubly-nested `NOT EXISTS`) is to join the input list, group by `ParentId` and ensure that you have as many matches as there are rows in the input list.

You should pass your data in as a Table Valued Parameter. As a hack you can convert to a table variable using `STRING_SPLIT`, but I'd advise you not to if possible.

Let us assume you have a Table Parameter `@input` of the form:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntList TABLE (Value int PRIMARY KEY /* must be unique */);
```

Then you can do as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input);

SELECT
  t.ParentID
FROM MyTable t
JOIN @input i ON i.Value = t.val
GROUP BY
  t.ParentID
HAVING COUNT(*) = @count;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7df46eb7188a8d4f39ed65ff5598283)

You may also want to take a look at other [Relational Division techniques](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/).